# Using self.xxxx as a default parameter - Python

Tags: python, object, recursion, tree

I'm trying to simplify one of my homework problems and make the code a little better. What I'm working with is a binary search tree. Right now I have a function in my `Tree()` class that finds all the elements and puts them into a list.

```
tree = Tree()
#insert a bunch of items into tree
```

then I use my makeList() function to take all the nodes from the tree and puts them in a list.
To call the `makeList()` function, I do `tree.makeList(tree.root)`. To me this seems a little repetitive. I'm already calling the tree object with `tree.`so the `tree.root` is just a waste of a little typing.

Right now the makeList function is:

```
    def makeList(self, aNode):
        if aNode is None:
            return []
        return [aNode.data] + self.makeList(aNode.lChild) + self.makeList(aNode.rChild)
```

I would like to make the aNode input a default parameter such as `aNode = self.root` (which does not work) that way I could run the function with this, `tree.makeList()`.

First question is, why doesn't that work?
Second question is, is there a way that it can work? As you can see the `makeList()` function is recursive so I cannot define anything at the beginning of the function or I get an infinite loop.

**EDIT**
Here is all the code as requested:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.lChild = None
        self.rChild = None

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def __str__(self):
        current = self.root

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def insert (self, item):
        newNode = Node (item)
        current = self.root
        parent = self.root

        if self.root == None:
            self.root = newNode
        else:
            while current != None:
                parent = current
                if item < current.data:
                    current = current.lChild
                else:
                    current = current.rChild

            if item < parent.data:
                parent.lChild = newNode
            else:
                parent.rChild = newNode

    def inOrder(self, aNode):
        if aNode != None:
            self.inOrder(aNode.lChild)
            print aNode.data
            self.inOrder(aNode.rChild)

    def makeList(self, aNode):
        if aNode is None:
            return []
        return [aNode.data] + self.makeList(aNode.lChild) + self.makeList(aNode.rChild)


    def isSimilar(self, n, m):
        nList = self.makeList(n.root)
        mList = self.makeList(m.root) 
        print mList == nList
```

Comment: What do you want with 'self' within a module level method? This makes absolutely no seense. If makeList2() is a method of class then please provide correct code and not snippets without context.

Comment: makeList2() was suppose to be makeList(), I edited it

Comment: How does this make no sense? I'm trying to use my makeList() function simpler by using a default parameter for the root of the tree instead of having to call it.

Comment: I agree with @crh878 that this makes sense. I tried it myself, also for creating a binary search tree. No joke...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

larsmans [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555449/using-self-xxxx-as-default-parameter-python/5555470#5555470) your first question

For your second question, can you simply look before you leap to avoid recursion?

```
def makeList(self, aNode=None):
    if aNode is None:
        aNode = self.root
    treeaslist = [aNode.data]
    if aNode.lChild:
        treeaslist.extend(self.makeList(aNode.lChild))
    if aNode.rChild:
        treeaslist.extend(self.makeList(aNode.rChild))
    return treeaslist
```

Answer (score 63):

It doesn't work because default arguments are evaluated at function definition time, not at call time:

```
def f(lst = []):
    lst.append(1)
    return lst

print(f()) # prints [1]
print(f()) # prints [1, 1]
```

The common strategy is to use a `None` default parameter. If `None` is a valid value, use a singleton sentinel:

```
NOTHING = object()

def f(arg = NOTHING):
    if arg is NOTHING:
        # no argument
    # etc.
```

Comment: You can omit the `Sentinel`. Just use `NOTHING = object()`. Guaranteed to yield a unique singleton you can check for via `is`.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against making `foo(1, None)` and `foo(1)` do different things.

Comment: @Glenn: with a one-arg function that must deal with arbitrary objects, it can make sense sometimes.

Comment: Ok, I understand why it doesn't work and also how your first code segment continually appends whatever value you add but I'm not fully following what's going on in the second code segment.

Comment: @crh878: the point about using `None` is the most important. The second part constructs an object `NOTHING`, uses that as the default argument and checks whether that exact object was passed in. If you hide `NOTHING` (don't export it from your module), it cannot be passed in by client code. `is` compares objects by memory address.

Comment: @larsmans ok I'm getting it. So if you something like a list, Python will continue to add on to that list even after it is done running that function, thus the function is useless if it is ran more than once? But if you assign the value to None and then change it, the function is reusable?

Comment: @chr878: you've got it. But actually, the `list` version may be useful sometimes, if you remember this behavior and document it well; it's very like introducing a global variable. I've seen libraries do this. But the `None` version is far more common.

Comment: Why we should use this instead of None?

Comment: @Charlestone in case you need to use None to mean something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to treat `None` as a valid argument, you could use a `**kwarg` parameter.

```
def function(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('arg3', default)
    arg3 = kwargs['arg3']
    
    # Continue with function

function("amazing", "fantastic") # uses default
function("foo", "bar", arg3=None) # Not default, but None
function("hello", "world", arg3="!!!")
```

I have also seen `...` or some other singleton be used like this.

```
def function(arg1, arg2=...):
    if arg2 is ...:
        arg2 = default
```